# Need to get the coordinates of the points in my arraylist from the index number and store in a new arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I currently have a program which tells the user what point in my arraylist they are closest to when they click on the screen. Currently, a toast appears which tells them the index number of the point they are closest to in the arraylist.
I need to be able to get the value at that index i.e. the point's coordinate to put into a new arraylist. mPoints being the arraylist with the points (100,100), (400,100), (100,400) and (400,400). I tried setting NPCords to the value of the index but this is not working.

```
   float Cox = event.getX();
              float Coy = event.getY();

              double CoX = (double) Cox;
              double CoY = (double) Coy;
              //the euclid method only accepts double numbers therefore the coordinates of the
              //points the user is clicking on need to be converted from float to double


              Double NearestDistance = 1000.12; //this is hardcoded for the sake of declaring the variable.
              int NearestPoint = -1; //this is hardcoded for the sake of declaring the variable.

              int NPCords = 0;
              for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
                  double xi;
                  double yi;
                  double dis;
                  xi = mPoints.get(i).x;
                  yi = mPoints.get(i).y;

                  dis = Euclid(CoX, CoY, xi, yi);
                  if (dis < NearestDistance) {
                      NearestPoint = i;
                      NearestDistance = dis;
                  }
                 // NPCords = Array.getInt(mPoints, NearestPoint);


              }

              String text = "the closest point to where you clicked is: " + NearestPoint + " and the coordinates are: " + NPCords;
              Toast.makeText(mContext, text, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String text = "the closest point to where you clicked is: " + NearestPoint + " and the coordinates are: (" + mPoints.get(NearestPoint).x + ", " + mPoints.get(NearestPoint).y + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (I'm assuming that mPoints is a List of Point).

I have changed some variable names to match Java Code Conventions

```
        double cox = (double)event.getX();
        double coy = (double)event.getY();

        Double nearestDistance = 1000.12; // this is hardcoded for the sake
                                            // of declaring the variable.
        Point nearestPoint = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < mPoints.size(); i++) {
            Point current = mPoints.get(i);
            double xi = current.x;
            double yi = current.y;

            double dis = Euclid(cox, coy, xi, yi);
            if (dis < nearestDistance) {
                nearestDistance = dis;
                nearestPoint = current;
            }
        }

        String text = "the closest point to where you clicked is: "
                + nearestPoint + " and the coordinates are: "
                + nearestPoint.x + ", " + nearestPoint.y;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, text, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Please take into account that you must check for nulls because nearestPoint can be null

Comment: Thank you! I found a way just before I saw your answer but this is more cleaner than my solution.